# Magento 1.8.0.0 - Worldpay payment response receiving 301 error

Tags: php, magento, redirect, response, worldpay

Good Morning,

I have recently been handed a Magento site that functions fine, however the callback integration between Worldpay and Magento seems to fail.

E-mails are sent to me stating that the server is responding with a 301 error (I believe this is a redirection error).

The URL that Worldpay is posting back to is http://www.[OURDOMAIN].com/worldpay/processing/response/

However I understand that Worldpay does not allow this? It used to work fine until recently. So now I have orders with payment status's as "Pending" even though they have been successful.

Can anybody provide some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was wondering, we fixed this by upgrading the installation from 1.8.0.0 to the latest Magento 1.9.1.1 with all security patches.